# find a composite function that makes a stepwise function continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, special-functions, continuity

This question is related to my another question posted earlier, and I think if this question can be answered, there might be a chance of answering my earlier posted one.

Given a non-decreasing stepwise function $g(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^N a_i1_{A_i}(\alpha)$, ($1_{A_i}(\alpha)=1$ if $\alpha \in A_i$ and $0$ otherwise), which is upper semicontinuous, is it possible to find a non-decreasing $f$ such that $f(g)$ becomes continuous?

Comment: Do you also mean "non-constant" for f?

Comment: You mean $f\circ g$ not $f(g)$, right?